# Data list results not disalying in my page

Tags: asp.net

I tried the code below for displaying results in data list. When user logs in, I tried to pull the data according to their id, but the details do not display, here is my code:

```
string connn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connn);
con.Open();
string str = "select details,address 
              from tb_userdata 
              inner join tb_userlogin 
              on tb_userdata.uidfromtb1=tb_userlogin.id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is missing WHERE statement. What you have in your query should show details for all users and not only for that specific user.

Try something like this and just update the part where parameter value is added

```
    string connn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connn);
    con.Open();
    string str = "select details,address from tb_userdata inner join tb_userlogin on tb_userdata.uid=tb_userlogin.id WHERE tb_userlogin.uid = @UID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UID", "retrieve UID somehow");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
```

Comment: yes sir,i tried but i have error ike this Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'haelzxpdrhkgwxpufxoughp4' to data type int.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please post your table definitions and eventually the code you use to login people on your website. If there a column in your tables that accepts values like 'haelzxpdrhkgwxpufxoughp4' ?